# storing JSON data in mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, arrays, json

I have an organization table for example

```
ID, name, address, phone, email, etc...
```

Now I want to add multiple addresses, phones and emails.

Is it a good way to store json data in email column like this

```
[ "address2@example2.com", "address2@example2.com", "address2@example2.com" ]
```

Or create another table just for emails and another for phones etc...

If storing json data is better - what is the best way to use it in rails?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is what I found

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html

> Saving arrays, hashes, and other non-mappable objects in text columns

Answer (score 1):

Storing data as a JSON string in a single database field means that you will not be able to manipulate/query the data using SQL - which kind of defeats the point of storing the data in a database, you may as well store it in a text file.

I'd recommend a [one-to-many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_%28data_modeling%29) relationship between your organization table and tables for email addresses and phone numbers. See [video explaining different relationship types](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RXOj0D80kRg)

Comment: Thansk. I think that sql way is better but here is the problem.
I am not using multiple emails only in "organization" table.
For example if I have 4 tables and each of them needs multiple phones, emails and addresses is this a best way to create "organization_emails", "organization_phones", "organization_addresses", "othertable_emails", etc...?

Comment: In this case you need a 'junction' or 'join' table (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) so your join table might contain the following fields: `ID` (this will be the othertable.id or organizations.id), `Type` (this will identify which table this record is for, I usually just have this as varchar and use a string to identify and index it) and `telephone_id` this will tell you where to fetch the telephone number from

Comment: Or if you have only got 2 tables you could just have `organization_id` and `othertable_id` in your telephone table

Answer (score 0):

suggest you store those information in a single table.
according to your requirement.it seems use a good polymorphic model will be better.

The code may like this.

```
module MultiAttr

  def self.included(base)
    base.send :extend, ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def multi_attr(*args)
      args.each do |attr_name|
        class_eval <<-EOF
          has_many attr_#{attr_name}, :class_name => "MultiAttributes", :as => :owner,
             :conditions => {:key => '#{attr_name.singularize}'}

          def add_#{attr_name.singularize}(val)
            self.attr_#{attr_name}.create(:key => #{attr_name.singularize}, :value => val)
            #{attr_name}
          end

          def #{attr_name}
            self.attr_#{attr_name}.map(&:to_attr_model)
          end

        EOF
      end
    end

  end


end

class AttrModel < String

  def initialize(record)
    @record = record
    super(record.value)
  end

  def remove
    @record.destroy
  end

end


#owner_type, owner_id, key, value
class MultiAttribute < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, :polymorphic => true

  def to_attr_model
    @attr_model ||= AttrModel.new(self)
  end
end
```

how to use

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include MultiAttr
  multi_attr :emails, :addresses
end

user.emails #=> ["abc@example.com"]
user.add_email "qq@example.com" #=> 
user.emails.first.remove
```

these codes not tested. but its my basic idea.